# Angular Material Data Table - not able to sort or paginate yet is viewable and can filter

Tags: angular, typescript

Table can be viewed properly and filtering data works. Source of Data feed coming from JSON.Pagination and sorting not working. Error in console is:

**TypeError: Cannot set property 'paginator' of undefined at ProductListComponent.ngAfterViewInit.**

Have tried different points defining paginator (in the constructor, etc) but this one had my neck hair up.

```
    product-list-component.ts
    product-list-component.html
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalService } from '../../services/global.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from '../../services/product.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class ProductListComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // JB This dictates the order of the fields displayed on the Mat tables
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'sku', 'name', 'description'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Product>;
  products;
  // JB Used to see if user can access page
  account: User = new User();
  userSub: Subscription;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  constructor(private global: GlobalService,
    private router: Router,
    private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSub = this.global.user.subscribe(
      me => this.account = me
    );
    if ( localStorage.getItem('token') && localStorage.getItem('account')) {
      this.global.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('account'));
      this.getProducts();
      // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.getProducts());
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      // this.router.navigateByUrl(['/#/authenticatin/login']);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
  getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.products = response;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
        console.log('products', response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error', error);
        // this.snackBar.open('Error getting movies JB...', '', { duration: 3000});
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
  <div fxFlex.gt-sm="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
      <mat-card>
          <mat-card-content> 
              <mat-card-title>Active products available for Custom. -Jared</mat-card-title>
              <div class="bg-light p-10 p-r-20 p-l-20">
                  <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Jared Search...">
                  </mat-form-field>
              </div>    
              <div class="table-rasponsive">
                  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

                  <!-- ID Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Progress Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="sku">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SKU </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.sku}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Name Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                   <!-- Description Column -->
                   <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.description}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Color Column
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Color </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </mat-cell>
                  </ng-container>  -->

                  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
                  </mat-row>
                </mat-table>

                <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
              </div>    
          </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Styles</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let product of products;" class="movieClickable">
      <h4>{{ product.sku }} {{ product.description }}</h4>
  </div>
  <button mat-ripple mat-raised-button color="accent">Add New Product</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to access `dataSource` in `ngAfterViewInit`, but at this stage `dataSource` might not be set yet since it's assigned when `productServices.getProducts()` is finished, which might be after `ngAfterViewInit`

You could assign the paginator after creating the table in your subscribe method

```
  getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      response => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

But there is still the risk that the call completes before `paginator` is set

The other solution is create an empty datasource in the constructor, set the paginator like you already do, but just update the data in your subscribe

```
      constructor()
      {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
      }

      //...
      getProducts() {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
        response => {
        this.dataSource.data =  response as Product[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any *ngIf in the html which hides the mat-table, that may resolve the issue